# <c:url value="/url"/> in an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

How can I use `<c:url value="/url">` in an external js file that contains jquery code in it?

This is an excerpt from my external js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : '<c:url value="/url.htm" >',
        dataType : "application/json",
        success : function(data) {
            // do something          
        },
        error : function(data) {
            // do something else
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you can't elegantly, you would have to have your server parse all .js files as jsp files which is probably a bad idea. Either store that data on an html element, or on the global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your container to process `*.js` files as `*.jsp` files; whether or not you should ... debateable.

Alternatives include putting some information in the JSP and passing it to methods defined in the external JSP file, putting the information in the DOM somewhere/somehow, and so on.